# Reading Hex from command line to unsigned char and unsigned short

Tags: c

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned char Data = 0xff;
    unsigned short addr = 0xff;

    sscanf(argv[1], "%u", &Data);
    sscanf(argv[2], "%hu", &addr);

    printf("data is %u addr is %hu ", Data, addr);

    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I am trying to read command line arguments of hex format into unsigned char and unsigned short. Please check the above code snippet. The output is always 0xff (initialized value). May I know what needs to be changed to read the inputs?

Comment: `%u` is incorrect format specifier for `Data` declared as `char`

Comment: Also, what values do you type in when prompted?

Comment: command to run: ./out 0x1e 0x2e

Answer (score 3):

By using the `%u` specifier you tell `sscanf` that you want to read an `an unsigned int` in decimal format (base 10). If you want hex input (base 16) you must use the `%x` specifier. Further you need to specify the correct integer size. For `unsigned char` you will need `hh` as length modifier. Using the wrong length modifier is a cause of undefined behaviour.

So you should try the `%hhx` specifier. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    unsigned char Data = 0xff;

    char argv1[20] = "0x40";

    sscanf(argv1, "0x%hhx", &Data);

    printf("data is %u\n", Data);

    return 0;

}
```

> Output: data is 64

For `unsigned short` in hex you should use `%hx`

Comment: I tried with `%x` which should fail but it worked. Why? Because I was on a PC and it's little endian? Did the stack got corrupted afterwards?

Comment: It could work. However, 1) it will corrupt memory outside the Data; 2) on systems that do not allow unaligned access and in case the Data is misaligned with int type, it will cause segfault

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre When using the incorrect specifier like I did first (i.e. %x) the `sscanf` expects a `int*` and it may write more than just an `unsigned char`. In other words, write outside the allocated memory (and cause UB). It was a mistake from my side to write `%x` in the orginal answer- it has been corrected now (with help from Serge).

Comment: The correct term is _undefined behaviour_. That is something one should avoid under all circumstances.

Comment: @Olaf apart from mentioning the UB it is important to show what IS the UB ;)

Comment: @Serge I leave that to you or the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

The `unsigned char` specificier for C99 and later is `%hhx`